# parse error in css3 using @media

Tags: css, media-queries

can't get the following to not throw a parse error in css3

```html
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  div#headerWrapper,
  div#navSuppWrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: this is quiet unclear, care to explain better?

Comment: Specific error please! Looks totally fine from here...

Comment: Paste the error here please

Comment: Please also add browser and version, CSS works fine with no parse error although the following is  overqualified: div#navSuppWrapper, the ID should be more than enough here.

Answer (score 1):

Never been a fan of !important in css but here is a basic media query template, the last query at the bottom should fix your problem.

```
/* #### Mobile Phones Portrait #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){

}

/* #### Mobile Phones Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape){



}

/* #### Mobile Phones Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px){
  @media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){




}
}

/* #### iPhone 4+ Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
 @media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){




}
}

/* #### Tablets Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){


}

/* #### Desktops #### */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){



}
```

Answer  `@media screen and` this is required.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
  div#headerWrapper,
  div#navSuppWrapper {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: how come this answer to the question?

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: `screen and` is required since when?? That's wrong.

Comment: Since I ran it through w3 css validator.

Comment: so [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) is wrong ?

Comment: So rather than put up a solution yourself, you're going to sit and prattle on? Don't you have some thread to edit or something?

Comment: As you can see this question is off topic therefore I didn't provide an answer.

Comment: And if English isn't his first language?  A little bit of compassion wouldn't go a miss now and then.